# Syntax error insert while creating element

Tags: java

I'm trying to build up simple balance system which I could control with not much elements as getbalance, setbalance, but the problem is that now I'm trying to make setbalance with user input, but I only started java today, so as example I'll set the balance with random generated number. And the problem I get is that syntax error insert. 
My code :

```java
package javatest;

import java.util.Random;

public class testas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // New coding started *2019/09.08
        //TODO *RANDOM MATCH ID.
        //TODO *Random sk (Dice)

        //TODO Bets on dice
        Random MatchID = new Random();
        int Matchoidas = MatchID.nextInt(999999999);
        //Convert Integer to string
        String mch1 = Integer.toString(Matchoidas);
        mch1 = "ID"+ mch1 + "sf";
        Random sk = new Random();
        int ska = sk.nextInt(6);
        ska += 1;
        int value = ska;
        System.out.println("Match: " + mch1 +" You rolled: " + ska + "\nYour ballance : " + balance);

    }

    private static double balance;
    private int accnr;

    public double setbalance(value) {

        balance = value;
    }

    public double getbalance() {

        return balance;
    }

    public int getaccnr() {

            return accnr;
        }

    }
```

*EDIT PROBLEM OCURS IN Setbalance line.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: There are to many problems which make your question too broad. Try to think about following decisions: why `balance` is static, why `setter` doesn't have type for its parameter, why setter has return type? Also since many people may want to have their own balance, each should be represented by specific *instance* of your class, and that instance should be created and used.

Comment: @Pshemo I was thinking about that everyone has their own balance and that's why I started to worry about public and private classes or how could I call them?

Comment: For now consider learning about what `static` keyword means. In sort: static member are part of class rather than instance. Even if you write `instanceA.staticMember` and `instanceB.staticMember` where `instanceA` and `instanceB` are instances of same class, compiler will see it as you would write `YourClass.staticMember` so you are accessing *same* variable. If you want each instance hold its own value in a field you can't make that field static.

Answer (score 3):

To make it compile you need to declare the type of the parameter `value` and return something since the return type is `double`.

```
  public double setbalance(double value) {
      return balance = value;
  }
```

Though, a standard setter would look like

```
  public void setBalance(double value) {
      balance = value;
  }
```

Comment: Hey, after trying these and some editing, I tried to change the value to 500, but when the system.out.println shows up the balance is 0

Comment: @DziuGas a `testas` object was never created and you didn't use its method

Answer (score 0):

You have some issues in your code :

1. Its better to create a separate class which contain the necessary attributes and contructor and getter setters
2. when you want to use this information create an Object and pass the values to this contructor
3. you have to read the correct way how to define getters and setter and the logic behind this

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined the parameter type in your setter method. You have defined it like

```
public double setbalance(value) {
    balance = value;
}
```

It will give compile time error. You have to write it as follow

```
public double setbalance(double value) {
    return this.balance = value;
}
```

But the standard way of writing setter method should be as follow:-

1. It should not return any value. Return type of this method should be **void**

Example :-

```
public void setBalance(double value) {
    this.balance = value;
}
```

Hope this will help.